# Problem on two ideals and their quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> For two ideals $I$ and $J$ in a commutative ring $R$, define $I : J = \{a\in
> R : aJ \subset I\}$. In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of all integers, if $I = 12\mathbb {Z}$ and $J = 8\mathbb {Z}$, find $I : J$.

How should I  solve this problem? Can anyone help me please? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Start by solving the relation $a (8 \mathbb{Z}) \subseteq (12 \mathbb{Z})$ for $a$. Find an equivalent condition on $a$ if this one is too strange to solve. P.S. this is usually called the "colon ideal" or sometimes "ideal quotient": index is something different.

Comment: @gumti $I:J$ is called the [quotient ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient) not index.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Which integers $a$ have the property that $a\cdot 8$ is a multiple of $12$?

If $a\cdot 8$ is a multiple of $12$, what can you say about $a\cdot x$ where $x$ is any multiple of $8$?

What does that tell you about the ideal $aJ$, where $J=(8)=\{\text{multiples of }8\}$?